# listen on more than one port and map port to another domain

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Blow is my current configuration for my server running nginx, gunicorn and Django. This all works. However I have added some monitoring app that runs on port 5555. How to I give access to this?

Do I add another listen setting, can I map it to another domain?

```
upstream app_server_djangoapp {
    server localhost:8002 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    #EC2 instance security group must be configured to accept http connections over Port 80
    listen 80;
    server_name testdomain.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/guni-error.log info;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Size in megabytes to allow for uploads.
    client_max_body_size 20M;

    # path for static files
    root /home/username/webapps/guni/static;

    location /docs/  {
                autoindex on;
                alias /srv/site/docs/buildHTML/html/;
    }



    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server_djangoapp;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic block that will make yourdomain.tld point to the monitoring app:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourdomain.tld;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ip-of-probably-flower-server:5555;
        }
```

Comment: Can I do this with a sub domain i.e. api.yourdomain.tld ?

Comment: Yes.  Just change the server_name directive.